# JavaScript cannot run <span> in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, sharethis

I'm trying to use [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) (A sharing tool) on my website.

I have an external JavaScript file that will imports all html codes by using innerHTML.

So the code basically runs like this:

```
document.getElementById("social_media").innerHTML = "<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>";
```

And the Header contains all the necessary files to run this span tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "de187292-9a6b-41ad-b7c6-a041b541f753", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

Ideally, `<span class='st_facebook_large'` will convert into a facebook share button, but I can't get the  tag to work properly.

Please help, thanks so much.

Comment: _"But I can't get the span tag to work"_ - meaning he is sitting on the couch all day and doing nothing? or is it something else you wanted to say... Explain please.

Comment: Take a look at http://codeforbrowser.com/sachin/ and see how its done. I am not sure why you need doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false in your publisher id

Comment: Maybe this code: `document.getElementById("social_media").innerHTML = "<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>";` is running AFTER the ShareThis code that does the magic? Can't you place a normal span tag in your HTML markup instead of generating it via Javascript?

Comment: I think you're forgetting to wait the onload event fireup to start your code.

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer? IE treats innerHTML as a read-only property when used with certain DOM elements. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me.

Please make sure that

```
document.getElementById("social_media").innerHTML = "<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>";
```

is called **after** the element with the id `social_media` was created but **before** the shareThis-Script runs.

It have to look somehow like this:

```
<div id="social_media"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "de187292-9a6b-41ad-b7c6-a041b541f753", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("social_media").innerHTML = "<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>";
</script>
```

**How to break my example:** If you put the div at the bottom of the page it wont work. ;-)

Comment: Great tip, i wrote another js function to run the buttons.js before the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>      
<div id="social_media" ></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("social_media").innerHTML = "<span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>";       
</script>
```

Just make sure you write the innerHTML after the element